# How to get the sequence number of the REPL prompt you are on

Tags: julia

In Julia programming, it's convenient to write and test some new functions in the REPL.
Sometimes I will get error messages point to REPL[x], x is the sequence number of the current REPL session I was on. Currently when I encounter this kind of issue, I need to scroll back the history and count the number of prompt untill I find x, but it's really inefficient. Is there any API I can use so that I can find my current prompt's sequence number, so I don't need to count from the beginning.

Comment: Off-site resource requests are off-topic

Comment: Can you give some code for reproducing this? I don't see any REPL[x] codes in my REPL. Usually images are bad but perhaps a screenshot wouldn't go astray in this case too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can have 'numbered prompt mode', similar to ipython. From the documentation here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/REPL/#Numbered-prompt

> It is possible to get an interface which is similar to the IPython
> REPL and the Mathematica notebook with numbered input prompts and
> output prefixes. This is done by calling `REPL.numbered_prompt!()`. If
> you want to have this enabled on startup, add
>
> ```
> atreplinit() do repl
>     @eval import REPL
>     if !isdefined(repl, :interface)
>         repl.interface = REPL.setup_interface(repl)
>     end
>     REPL.numbered_prompt!(repl)
> end
> ```
>
> to your startup.jl file.

It should at least work for version >=1.9